# Generic Method with optional generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics

How do I create a generic method with an optional generic type? This is what I have right now, which works

```
 public GridViewColumn<T> Column<D>(String HeaderText, D decorator) where D: IColumnDecorator, new()
        {
            GridViewColumn<T> column = new GridViewColumn<T>();
            column.HeaderText = HeaderText;
            column.Decorator = new D();
            return column;
        }
```

As you can see, I need to instantiate the type D (implements IColumnDecorator) inside the Column() method.

The issue is, the type "D" is optional. If Null, I want to explicitly use a default ColumnDecorator that I have. something like

```
 public GridViewColumn<T> Column<D>(String HeaderText, D decorator) where D: IColumnDecorator, new()
        {
            GridViewColumn<T> column = new GridViewColumn<T>();
            column.HeaderText = HeaderText;
            if(decorator ==null)
            {
               column.Decorator = new DefaultColumnDecorator();
            }
            else{
               column.Decorator = new D();
            }
            return column;
        }
```

Please help. Thanks!

[Edit].

Here is how I want to use it in razor MVC if I have a custom IColumnDecorator implementation

```
@Model.[IEnumerable].Grid(grid=>{
      ..
      ...
      grid.columns(
         grid.Column<MyOwnColumnDecorator>("FirstColumn")
      )
});
```

If I don't have any and want to use default, then I want to be able to do something like

```
@Model.[IEnumerable].Grid(grid=>{
          ..
          ...
          grid.columns(
             grid.Column("FirstColumn",null) or simply grid.Column("FirstColumn"); 
          )
    });
```

Comment: Why does your first method have the caller pass in an instance of `D` at all? You never use it.

Comment: Why do you need to instantiate type `D` inside `Column()`? It would be much more flexible to let the caller pass in the instance.

Comment: Justin, what do you mean? and Yuxiu, i did that because I do not want my caller to have to specify "new" keyword of a concrete type when they call.

Comment: If you want a default ColumnDecorator, just do overloading. Have a non-generic overload - which uses your columndecorator. It doesn't make sense to provide a (non-null) default for generics.... that's more in line with an interface parameter.

Comment: You won't be able to use it like that. You are hard coding the type of decorator in this call, when you try to instantiate the DefaultDecorator your code will not compile since your method is expecting a type of MyOwnColumnDecorator. I don't know if I explained myself.

Comment: Sergio, both MyOwnColumnDecorator and DefaultDecorator implement IColumnDecorator. Thanks.

Comment: @Justin, after reading others comment, just realized what you meant! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your current code, you don't need the `decorator` parameter since you create a new instance of `D` and use that instead.

```
public GridViewColumn<T> Column<D>(String HeaderText) where D: IColumnDecorator, new()
{
    GridViewColumn<T> column = new GridViewColumn<T>();
    column.HeaderText = HeaderText;
    column.Decorator = new D();
    return column;
}
```

If you have a default parameter type to use, you don't need to use generics:

```
public GridViewColumn<DefaultColumnDecorator> Column(String headerText)
{
    return Column<DefaultColumnDecorator>(headerText);
}
```

Alternatively you could keep the parameter and remove the `new()` constraint:

```
public GridViewColumn<T> Column<D>(String HeaderText, D decorator) where D : IColumnDecorator
{
    GridViewColumn<T> column = new GridViewColumn<T>();
    column.HeaderText = HeaderText;
    column.Decorator = decorator;
    return column;
}

public GridViewColumn<DefaultColumnDecorator> Column(String headerText)
{
    return Column(headerText, new DefaultColumnDecorator());
}
```

Comment: new D() would be better written as default(D) and I like the rest of your proposed solution.

Comment: @phillip - `new D()` and `default(D)` are completely different - `default(D)` is null if `D` is a class type, and 'zero' if it's a struct.

Comment: In your 3rd code block without the new() constraint, the method doesn't need to be generic at all.

Comment: Thanks Lee. After trying all solutions, looks like this is the best way to approach it. Just overload the column method. If you have an implementation, use that. Otherwise, use the default one. 

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use a default parameter:

```
public GridViewColumn<T> Column<D,T>(string HeaderText, D decorator = null)
    where D : IColumnDecorator, class, new()
```

Comment: Thanks ShadowCat7, now, how do I call the method? Just supply a null as second parameter?

Comment: Default parameters allow you to not have to add the second parameter. You can call it by only supplying a string and the type parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be instantiating type `D` from the `Column` method. Instead, you should let the caller pass it in.

```
 public GridViewColumn<T> Column(String HeaderText, IColumnDecorator decorator) 
        {
            GridViewColumn<T> column = new GridViewColumn<T>();
            column.HeaderText = HeaderText;
            if(decorator ==null)
            {
               column.Decorator = new DefaultColumnDecorator();
            }
            else{
               column.Decorator = decorator;
            }
            return column;
        }
```

The rationale is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: Use the null coalescing operator and make decorator optional, but this is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with some options I made a sample that works with the following code:

```
public GridViewColumn<TResult> Column<TColumn>(string HeaderText, TColumn decorator = null) where TColumn : class, IColumnDecorator
{
    GridViewColumn<TResult> column = new GridViewColumn<TResult>();
    column.HeaderText = HeaderText;

     if(decorator == null)
     {
        column.Decorator = new DefaultColumnDecorator();
     }
     else
     {
        column.Decorator = decorator;  
     }     

    return column;
}
```

In order to make this work you need to consider the following:

- You need to add the class restriction in order to be able to define your parameter as null.
- You should not use **default(TColumn)** since it will return null because of the class restriction.
- For some reason if you use the "? :" syntax the compiler does not accept that you instantiate the DefaultColumnDecorator type but if you use a regular if statement it works.
- It seems the new() restriction is not necessary for this to work.

In my sample I was able to call this method in the following two ways with the same result:

```
@Model.[IEnumerable].Grid(grid=>{
      ..
      ...
      grid.columns(
         grid.Column<MyOwnColumnDecorator>("FirstColumn",null);
      )
});

@Model.[IEnumerable].Grid(grid=>{
      ..
      ...
      grid.columns(
         grid.Column<MyOwnColumnDecorator>("FirstColumn");
      )
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Wow, thanks Sergio! That's almost the same code as what I have now. The issue I forgot to mention is that in the above code, "MyOwnColumnDecorator" should be optional and only needed if you have a custom class that implements IColumnDecorator. Sorry, I'm bad at ask question.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to do what you're trying to do, how about asking the caller to pass a way to make a decorator?

```
public GridViewColumn<T> Column(string HeaderText, Func<IColumnDecorator> decoratorGenerator)
{
  GridViewColumn<T> column = new GridViewColumn<T>();
  column.HeaderText = HeaderText;
  column.Decorator = decoratorGenerator != null ? decoratorGenerator()
    : new DefaultColumnDecorator() ;
  return column;
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. The reason I don't want this approach is because I don't want to make it harder for end users to use it, so after all test/trails, I prefer Lee's approach. Thanks anyway though. Greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

I see two things you are missing.  One is a default parameter setting `decorator = null` and the other is the use of [`default(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  I have rewrote yours as follows but I can't test it obviously - should be close though.

```
public GridViewColumn<TResult> Column<TColumn>(string HeaderText, TColumn decorator = null) where TColumn : IColumnDecorator, new()
{
    GridViewColumn<TResult> column = new GridViewColumn<TResult>();
    column.HeaderText = HeaderText;
    column.Decorator = decorator == null ? new DefaultColumnDecorator() : default(TColumn);

    return column;
}
```

Comment: philip, how do i call this code if I want the decorator to either be optional or null? I tried to specify ...Column("Header Text", null), it says try to specify the usage explicitly.

Comment: Column("HeaderText") is all you have to do because the second parameter is specified already.

Comment: You should replace your `Decorator` assignment with something like `column.Decorator = decorator ?? new DefaultColumnDecorator();` since you are currently assigning null (if D is a class type) if `decorator` is provided by the caller.

Comment: Key Phillip, I tried do this ... grid.column("HeaderText"), but getting an error. but if i do supply a concrete type, then i'm fine like   grid.Column<MyOwnColumnDecorator>("FirstColumn"). btw, i had to add a "class" to the constraint, or else, it won't let me set to null

Comment: Using default(TColumn) is going to just give you null, but that's not what you want at all. You should use the null coalescing operator: column.Decorator = decorator ?? new DefaultColumnDecorator() or stick with Lee's solution. It's also worth nothing that if you aren't doing new D(), your second parameter can just be IColumnDecorator and it doesn't need to be generic at all.

Comment: Thanke lukegravitt. i adopted Lee's solution by overloading the method. Greatly appreciate it.